# Action listener, key board input

Tags: java, swing, action, actionlistener

im having problems with action listeners.
the problem is this:

```
 private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    int i;
    System.out.println("Created GUI on EDT? "+
    SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread());
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Best Game Ever");        
    JButton buttonA = new JButton("Press 'z'");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
    f.add(new MyPanel(),BorderLayout.CENTER);
    f.add(buttonA, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);      
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
    final char ACTION_KEY = 'z';
    final char ACTION_KEY2 ='x';
    Action actionListener = new AbstractAction()
    {          
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent)
        {
        }
    };

    Action actionListener2 = new AbstractAction()
    {          
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent)
        {
            System.out.println("x");
        }
    };      
    KeyStroke z = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('z');       
    InputMap inputMap = buttonA.getInputMap();
    inputMap.put(z, ACTION_KEY);
    ActionMap actionMap = buttonA.getActionMap() ;
    actionMap.put(ACTION_KEY, actionListener);        
    KeyStroke x = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('x');
    InputMap inputMap2 = buttonA.getInputMap();
    inputMap2.put(x, ACTION_KEY2);
    ActionMap actionMap2 = buttonA.getActionMap();
    actionMap2.put(ACTION_KEY2, actionListener2);        
}
```

i just cant make up a code for it to only print x once even when i hold the key.
thanks.

sorry for not putting all the code :(

hope it makes sence now.

Comment: where your action fired???

Comment: What's the problem you are facing?

Answer (score 1):

> "i just cant make up a code for it to only print x once even when i hold the key."

One way is to add `released` to the kestroke, It will only print when the key is released

```
   inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released X"), "printX");
```

> A KeyStroke represents a key action on the keyboard, or equivalent input device. KeyStrokes can correspond to only a press or release of a particular key, just as KEY_PRESSED and **KEY_RELEASED** KeyEvents do; alternately, they can correspond to typing a specific Java character, just as KEY_TYPED KeyEvents do.

```
Here's an example
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestKeyBind {

    public TestKeyBind() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        Action actionListener2 = new AbstractAction() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                System.out.println("x");
            }
        };
        InputMap inputMap = panel.getInputMap(JPanel.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        ActionMap actionMap = panel.getActionMap();

        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released X"), "printX");
        actionMap.put("printX", actionListener2);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TestKeyBind();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

You could also try `typed` but the "key typed" event operates per platform. It won't work on Windows, I just tried it